# How to use the text field data and calculate through the api call in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, backend, flutter-test

Actually today I decided to make a love calculator and for that I learnt the http call in flutter but now I am stuck at a point and I don't know how to move onwards.

```
import 'package:AllInOneCalci/Post.dart';
import 'package:AllInOneCalci/customAppBar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

class LoveCalUI extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var AppBarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: customAppBar(
        height: (AppBarHeight / 3) * 0.4,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 18.0),
              child: Text(
                'All In One Cali',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 35.0,
                    fontFamily: 'DancingScript',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: CustomFetchData(),
    );
  }
}

class CustomFetchData extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomFetchDataState createState() => _CustomFetchDataState();
}

class _CustomFetchDataState extends State<CustomFetchData> {
  Future<Post> getData() async {
    final response =
        await http.get('https://love-calculator.p.rapidapi.com/getPercentage?fname=John&sname=Alice');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return Post.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load api');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
            child: FutureBuilder<Post>(
                future: getData(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return Center(
                        child: Text('Please Wait while its loading...'));
                  } else {
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
                    } else {
                      return Center(
                        child: Text('${snapshot.data}'),
                      );
                    }
                  }
                })),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  // ignore: must_call_super
  void initState() {
    getData();
  }
}
```

This is a lovecalculator class where I am coding all the stuffs. If there is any NEWS website, where the data is fetching from the api call then it will be very easy.

**But I want that I enter two names in the text field and the process is now calculated through api i.e the logic is written at the backend and I want to fetch that logic into my code ()given that I HAVE TO ENTER THE NAMES. Can you help me please. I have given that api reference here. If anyone could help me, then it will be very supporting.**

api reference- https://rapidapi.com/ajith/api/love-calculator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you already can use [text field controllers and extract text](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes). The thing you needed to include to your request are headers which include important key information.

If you [look here](https://rapidapi.com/ajith/api/love-calculator), you can find reference for several languages request example (for example I used Swift for reference). Below you can see how to do it in Flutter:

In your `pubspec.yaml`

```
http: ^0.12.2
```

In your `.dart` file you need to import

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

Also you need to pick a place which would call a function, in my case it was a button from default Flutter starter project:

```
Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'love-calculator.p.rapidapi.com',
    'x-rapidapi-key': 'insert your API key from website',
  };

void _getNames({String name1, String name2}) async {
    final response = await http.get(
      'https://love-calculator.p.rapidapi.com/getPercentage?fname=$name1&sname=$name2',
      // Send authorization headers to the backend.
      headers: requestHeaders,
    );

    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
    print(responseJson);
  }
```

Comment: Thanku So Much for helping me. I just asked another question please reply it...waiting for your response and once again thanku so much.

Comment: @ShîvamYadav you are welcome) send me the question, I will try to help

Comment: Yes sir, I have just posted it. Please answer. Thank you so much for all your responses:}